# nodejs ajax local passport | user data req.user registered to user

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, passport.js

I want to log in with ajax.
I want user information to be recorded in the request parameter.

But when I do it with ajax, user information is not registered in the request parameter.

so req.user --> undefined

he's turning.
How can I solve this?

local auth passport codes:

```
const LocalStrategy = require("passport-local").Strategy;
const passport = require("passport");
const bcrypt = require("bcrypt");
const User = require("../models/User");

passport.use(
  "user-login",
  new LocalStrategy(
    {
      usernameField: "email",
    },
    (email, password, done) => {
      User.findOne(
        {
          email,
        },
        (err, user) => {
          if (err) return done(err, null, "Bir hata olustu");
          if (!user) {
            return done(null, false, "Böyle bir email yok.");
          }

          bcrypt.compare(password, user.password, (err, res) => {
            if (res) {
              return done(null, user, "Başarıyla giriş yapıldı.");
            } else {
              return done(null, false, "Yanlış şifre girildi");
            }
          });
        }
      );
    }
  )
);
passport.serializeUser(function (user, done) {
  console.log(user);
  done(null, user.id);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function (id, done) {
  User.findById(id, function (err, user) {
    console.log(user);

    done(err, user);
  });
});
```

router:

```
module.exports.postLogin = async (req, res, next) => {
  passport.authenticate("user-login", {
    successRedirect: "/",
    failureRedirect: "/users/login",
    failureFlash: true,
    successFlash: true,
  })(req, res, next);
}
```

app.js middleware

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  console.log(req.user);
  next();
});
```

print:

```
POST /admin/login 302 2304.994 ms - 23
{
  _id: 5fb8fa8c26cdfc239c4276b9,
  username: 'tolgaand',
  password: '$2b$10$XhifEgbN4mEiCGPvm/dF5.zHYlEPZW3Jhibjm4ABuhEeRJ34psYsu',
  name: 'Tolga',
  lastName: 'Çağlayan',
  title: 'Javascript Geliştiricisi',
  about: "mongodb'ye bağlandım olley",
  phone: '+90 534 393 6238',
  email: 'tolgaand@yandex.com',
  location: 'İstanbul / Türkiye',
  available: 'Müsait',
  permission: 0,
  __v: 0
}
{}
```

router with ajax (i want)

```
module.exports.postLogin = async (req, res, next) => {
  passport.authenticate("user-login", (error, user, info) => {
    if (error) {
      return res.json({ success: false, message: info.message });
    }
    if (!user) {
      return res.json({ success: false, message: info });
    }
    res.json({ success: true, message: info, user });
  })(req, res, next);
};
```

print:

```
POST /admin/login 200 998.327 ms - 446
undefined
{}
```

how can I do this with jquery / ajax?
instead of undefined, I just want user information to be registered as above.